# How to convert string ("0 100 300 200") to array of long in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

How can I convert string (of this form: "0 100 300 200") to array of long in Java (Android)?

Could you take a look at my code?

```
public long[] ConvertStringToLongArray(String tekst)
    {
        int L1 = tekst.length();
        long[] somelong = new long[L1];
        String[] tekstarray = tekst.split(" ");
        for (int i=0;i<=L1;i++)
        {
            somelong[i] = Long.parseLong(tekstarray[i]);
        }
        return somelong;
    }
```

This is a part of information application for school community.

I'm beginner in Java programming.

Comment: That code does it. What's the problem?

Comment: Be sure to explain on the application that the work is not entirely your own.

Answer (score 1):

The code is basically OK.
One bug you do have there, though, is initializing the length of `somelong` with `L1`. `L1` is the number of characters in `tekst`, so this will result with bunch of unintentional zeroes at the end of your array. The correct size would be the same size as `tekstarray`.

**EDIT:**
As Luiggi Mendoza commented, splitting by `"\\s+"` instead of `" "` would resolve any issue with the number being delimited by more than one space.

```
public long[] ConvertStringToLongArray(String tekst)
{
    String[] tekstarray = tekst.split("\\s+");
    long[] somelong = new long[teksarray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i <= somelong.length; i++)
    {
        somelong[i] = Long.parseLong(tekstarray[i]);
    }
    return somelong;
}
```

Comment: In fact, it would be better splitting by `"\\s+"` in order to avoid additional blank spaces between the numbers.

Comment: replace L1 with tekstarray.length

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza tru 'dat. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! I like the '"\\s+"' idea and thanks for 'tekstarray.length' :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. Change size of L1 to

```
L1 = tekstarray.length;
```

You also need to remove = in your for loop.

```
for (int i=0;i <L1;i++)
```

Comment: Thank you! My application is running now correctly.